# re-route of traffic is not working with ingress controller. I feel i mis-understood the re-write annotation?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

Issue with re-write annotation.

Tried using re-write annotation. Not able to get that work.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-whale-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello.whale.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /blue|/(.+)
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-blue-whale-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /green|/(.+)
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-green-whale-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

/Green is showing perfect result , but why not /blue.

Comment: apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-whale-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello.whale.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /blue|/(.+)
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-blue-whale-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /green|/(.+)
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-green-whale-svc
          servicePort: 80

Comment: from individual services, able to get the result. not through ingress. Any issue with yml file ?

Comment: can you try like this: path: /blue/(.*)

Answer (score 0):

You should see in your logs that the ingress always hits the same backend. Maybe [this doc](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites) may help you.

I tested myself with two nginx servers as backends, one returning blue and the other green:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-whale-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=green rewrite=/;serviceName=blue rewrite=/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: stardust
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /green
        backend:
          serviceName: green
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /blue
        backend:
          serviceName: blue
          servicePort: 80
```

Then, using curl I can reach the right target:

```
$ curl stardust/green
green
$ curl stardust/blue
blue
```

And here are the logs of the ingress controller:

```
10.32.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2019:14:56:12 +0000] "GET /green HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "curl/7.64.1" 132 0.008 [default-green-80] [] 10.32.0.28:80 6 0.008 200 b5ac38db9dd6a7e53d316dc48e9401aa
10.32.0.1 - - [12/Oct/2019:14:56:16 +0000] "GET /blue HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "curl/7.64.1" 131 0.011 [default-blue-80] [] 10.32.0.12:80 5 0.012 200 c438d22db0e80a5206ca8885a48d72f9
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

> can you try like this: path: /blue/(.*) – Vasily Angapov 2 days ago

I'd like to add some words of explanation to *Vasily Angapov's* correct answer posted in question comments so everyone can understand why `/blue/(.*)` actually works and why `/blue|/(.+)` will not work and shouldn't be used in this context.

Let's use [regexp online interpreter](https://regexr.com/) which contains detailed explanation of every character used in our expression and let us experiment with matching different strings to the given regular expression:

`/blue|/(.+)` basically means we want to match string `/blue` or any other non-zero string. `.` means any character except of line termination and `+` sign is a quantifier which tells us how many times previous character may occur in our string. `+` denotes one or more occurrences of preceding character so the expression `.+` matches a string consisting of one or more different characters (excluding line break).

If you construct an ingress path to be matched with specific string you typically don't want to use `|`. In this particular context it would mean that you want to match `/blue` or `anything else` like `/green`, `/yellow`, `/red`... which doesn't make much sense in this context. You are rather interested to match paths only starting from `/blue` like `/blue/index.html`, `/blue/second.html` or `blue/third.php` or just `/blue` itself.
Your path may look like this:

`/blue/(.+)`

and it will match `/blue/index.html`, `/blue/1` but not `/blue` alone as `.+` matches **one or more arbitrary characters**.

`.*` on the other hand matches **zero or more arbitrary characters** so expression `/blue/(.*)` will match:

`/blue`, `/blue/index.html`, `/blue/`, `/blue/1` etc.